# Is there a shortcut way to create a new object if an object is null?

Tags: c#

I have some simple code:

```
    public static void InitializeScreenTimeStopwatch()
    {
        if (ScreenTimeStopwatch == null)
            ScreenTimeStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    }
```

Is there a simple way that this code can be refactored using the ? operator that's now with the latest version of C#

Comment: Null coalescing operator (`??`)?

Comment: Can I use that to eliminate the "if" in this case?

Comment: ```ScreenTimeStopwatch = ScreenTimeStopwatch ?? new Stopwatch();```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.ScreenTimeStopwatch = this.ScreenTimeStopwatch ?? new Stopwatch();
```

If you're using C# 8 then you can simply write this:

```
this.ScreenTimeStopwatch ??= new Stopwatch();
```